# Why does this C# class call the parent method instead of the child used in the generic?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, shadowing

Why does c# not call the `new Method1` from DerivedClass and instead calls Method1 on the BaseClass?

```cs
using System;
                    
class BaseClass  
{  
    public void Method1()  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Base - Method1");  
    }  
}  
  
class DerivedClass : BaseClass  
{  
    public new void Method1()  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method1");  
    }  
}  

class GenericClass<T> where T: BaseClass {
    public void CallMethod(T instT) {
        instT.Method1();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
        GenericClass<DerivedClass> gc = new GenericClass<DerivedClass>();
        gc.CallMethod(dc);
        dc.Method1();
    }
}
```

```
# outputs
Base - Method1
Derived - Method1
```

EDIT: The specification at [8.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#85-type-parameters)
say this. It seems related.

> The rules for member lookup on type parameters depend on the constraints, if any, applied to the type parameter. They are detailed in §11.5.

Comment: wouldn't you want `public virtual void Method1() ` on the base so it's overridable?

Comment: I'm not interested in a better version of this code. I'm interested in understanding why it behaves as it does. The result doesn't match my expectation (:  This is a simplified version of my problem and I cannot change the BaseClass. [Possibly relevant link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#845-satisfying-constraints)